# JDA - Get all channels from specific server

Tags: java, discord-jda

so i have a problem. I have a server. And i have JDA bot. I need to get ALL channels(voice, text) from that server. Possible it to make with JDA? Of course, bot see that channels.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the guild from the JDA instance [`jda.getGuildById(serverId)`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#getGuildById(long))
2. Then get a list of channels with [`guild.getChannels()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getChannels())

Note that `getGuildById` will not work immediately after building your JDA instance with the `JDABuilder`. The guild must first be initialized, you can use either the [`ReadyEvent`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/ReadyEvent.html) or [`JDA#awaitReady`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#awaitReady()) to delay your code appropriately.

Comment: yeh. Is it working. But, I getting Name, ID. Can i get only ID. Ex. of out ([GC:AWESOME CHANNEL(6434858340453))

Comment: If you have more questions, then open more questions instead of using comments.